# Google Maps with satellite base Map and imageMapType overlay increase zoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am displaying an ImageMapType as overlay over a satellite mapType base map. 
The base map seems to be limiting the max zoom to 19 in my area, if I change to a Road mapType I get a a couple of more levels. I have high resolution imaginery which I am displaying in the overlay and I want to be able to zoom further. If I use the ImageMapType as base map I can zoom in all I need, but I would really like to display the satellite base map and then continue to zoom into the image even if there's no satellite imaginery available.
Is there any way of accomplishing this? The only thing I can think of is creating a custom base map.

Code is similar to this example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image-overlay

Thanks!

My code:

```
var mapMinZoom = 10;
var mapMaxZoom = 25;
var zoom = 20;

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.567426059726316, -60.34467143006623),
        zoom: zoom,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        panControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        maxZoom: mapMaxZoom

      });
    createImageLayer('imaginery', 'images')
 }

function createImageLayer(key, folder) {
        var mapBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new                                   google.maps.LatLng(-34.55771388565057, -60.367219001054764), new google.maps.LatLng(-34.55817334541287, -60.3209562599659));

        var imageMapTypeLayer = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        minZoom: mapMinZoom,            
        maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
        name: key,  
        getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
            if ((zoom < mapMinZoom) || (zoom > mapMaxZoom)) {
               return "http://www.maptiler.org/img/none.png";
            }
            var ymax = 1 << zoom;
            var y = ymax - coord.y -1;

            var tileBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                          map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng( new google.maps.Point( (coord.x), (coord.y) )  ),
                          map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng( new google.maps.Point( (coord.x), (coord.y)))
                      );

            // write a real condition here, so long this is always valid
            if (tileBounds.intersects(tileBounds)) {
                      return "/static/ui/"+ folder +   "/"+zoom+"/"+coord.x+"/"+y+".png";
            } else {
               return "http://www.maptiler.org/img/none.png";
            }
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)
      });

    map.overlayMapTypes.push(imageMapTypeLayer)
}
```

**EDIT 1**:
Up to now I have managed to overcome this by listening to the zoom_changed event and changing the base map to my imageMapType when the zoom reaches the maximum and back to satellite when the user zooms out. I wonder if there's a cleaner solution to this issue.